# how to use java runtime.exec() and ssh to another machine to start a process

Tags: java, runtime.exec

is this the right approach?

```
 public void doSomething()
 {
    Process p;

    String[] cmd = {"/usr/bin/ssh", "someRemoteMachine", "/absPathToMyProg/myProg"};
    String[] envp = {"PATH=path_needed_toRun_myProg"};

    try
    {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd,envp);

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Epic Fail");
    }
 }
```

Comment: It looks like the right general idea, but I'm not convinced that the `PATH` will propagate through the SSH connection; why not invoke `myProg` based on its fully qualified path, if you know what this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from using JSch (or any other Java SSH implementation), like Suraj said, passing the Path via environment variables is likely not to work, since most SSH deamons only accept a small set of variables from the other side (mostly related to localization or terminal type).

As the argument to `ssh` (or the "command", if using JSch with an [ChannelExec](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html)) is passed to the remote shell for execution, you could try to define the path in this command (if your default shell is something compatible to the POSIX `sh`):

```
PATH=path_needed_toRun_myProg /absPathToMyProg/myProg
```

Your array for Runtime.exex thus would look like this:

```
String[] cmd = {"/usr/bin/ssh", "someRemoteMachine",
                "PATH=path_needed_toRun_myProg /absPathToMyProg/myProg"};
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). Its released under BSD type license. Its pure java and easy to use.

Comment: Yes, this is a much better solution than messing about with Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..)

Comment: By the way, it is even easier to use [with documentation](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/).